# How can I write binding to a C function that expects an open file handle in Rust?

Tags: rust, ffi

I've toyed with writing library bindings in Rust before, and it wasn't difficult. Now, however, I'm stuck: I'm trying to write a binding for [librsync](https://github.com/librsync/librsync), and some of its functions expect you to pass an open file handle (a `FILE*` in C).

For primitive types, there's a straightforward way to pass them into C, (the same for pointers to primitive types). And, to be clear, I'm aware that the `libc` crate implements `fopen`, which in turn gives me a `mut FILE*` (which would eventually do the job). However, I was wondering if there is something in the Rust standard library that gives me a `FILE*` to pass to `librsync` — maybe something analog to `std::ffi::CString`.

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to use the avenue that you already know? You have to tell us that so that any answers don't automatically fail for the same reason.

Comment: Mostly lacking proficiency with Rust, Shepmaster. I don't want to rush to a solution being unaware of the alternatives, if any exist.

Comment: It's unclear what are you asking for here, which in turns makes the question too broad I am afraid: do you want to avoid manipulating `*mut FILE` directly? or what?

Comment: Sorry, Matthieu. I've edited the text in the hopes of making it clearer.

Comment: So despite the accepted answer it seems like the cleanest thing is to use `libc::fopen`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could of course use a `RawFd`, transmute and call `libc::funcs::posix88::stdio::fdopen(_, mode)` with it. That would be highly unportable though.

Answer (score 0):

[cfile](https://github.com/flier/rust-cfile) ([crate docs](https://docs.rs/cfile/0.5.1/cfile/)) looks like a lightweight wrapper around libcs FILE* that implements the [io::Read/Write/Seek](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/#read-and-write) traits.